# How do we compare fixed int value with column whose contain special characters and number in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have query that fetches the `post_id` from  a table whose meta value is greater than or equal to 45. But the problem is `t1.meta_value` contains special characters with the number 106'-0" . I need only the 106 value for comparison purposes.

I have used the query below and it trims (45'-0") to 45. But only displaying time. I want to trim it at the time of comparing i.e `t1.meta_value >='45'`

Query:

```
select t1.post_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.meta_value,'\&',1) 
from wp_postmeta AS t1 
where (t1.meta_key LIKE '%_text_field_width%' AND t1.meta_value >='45')
order by t1.meta_value asc



select t1.post_id 
from wp_postmeta AS t1 
where (t1.meta_key LIKE '%_text_field_width%' AND t1.meta_value>='45')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use typecasting:

```
SELECT 
    t1.post_id,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.meta_value, '&', 1) AS SIGNED) AS m_value
FROM
    wp_postmeta AS t1
WHERE
    t1.meta_key LIKE '%_text_field_width%'
        AND m_value >= 45
ORDER BY m_value ASC
```

see more http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: not working saying unknown column m_value.But I got an idea with this query thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please give it a try if this works for you:

If `meta_value` always starts with a number then adding `0` to `meta_value` will convert it to number.

```
SELECT
    t1.post_id
FROM    wp_postmeta AS t1
WHERE
    (
        t1.meta_key LIKE '%_text_field_width%'
        AND (t1.meta_value+0) >= 45
    )
```